# How to use [Authorize] attribute in project which using MVC Portable Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, portable-areas

My project using MVC Portable Areas, its contain 2 projects, one is the main, and the other is Account project. In AccountController, I use [Authorize] attribute to redirect user to Login page, but I always receive "You don't have permission to access this directory". Any solution for me?

Comment: Does the Login page also require authorisation? Try decorating the Login action with `[AllowAnonymous]`.

Comment: Yes its already set `[AllowAnonymous]`, I mean if I put [Authorize] on top of `AccountController`, I can't access to all actions in it :( It didn't redirect to `Login` page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller code:

```
[Authorize]
public partial class AccountController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public virtual ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Root Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".FORM" loginUrl="area/account/login" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/"/>
</authentication>
```

It works without any problems in my project which using MVC Portable Areas.

Also, make sure that `[Authorize]` attribute redirect to the correct page and correct action method

Comment: To be safe, I would add the '~' in there to make sure the url resolves correctly like so loginUrl="~/area/account/login".

Comment: Thank `mexahuk` and `ryanulit`, its good answer but not my problem. I'm using MVC Portable Areas and ASP.NET Identity OWIN for authentication, the `Authorize` attribute require Nuget package `Microsoft.OWIN.Host.SystemWeb` to host the Identity features, after install that package, its working perfect. By the way, I accept your answer coz it is right answer.